# Does git merge --no-commit prevent any changes?

Tags: git, merge

If I'm unsure about a git merge, and I use git merge --no-commit, does this prevent any actual changes occurring in my repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you’d need to still do a git merge --abort, otherwise you’ve just got an uncommitted merge sitting there waiting for manual commits. Still a good safety measure though if you’re unsure about things.

Comment: So a git status would show the staged files, ready for commit?